# GCP Web Console Update: Removed Ability to Copy SSH keys and connect via gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

Google seems to have updated their web console, removing the ability to "copy ssh key for gcloud cli" when trying to ssh into a GCE (Compute Engine) instance. I was wondering how I can now access this pop up which gives you the ability to copy and paste the full key needed to ssh into the running instance?

Comment: Can you provide the steps on how to get to the said pop up "copy ssh key for gcloud cli"? The closest to it that I can see on the GCP web is "open using private SSH keys" and based on the official [Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes) on Compute Engine, there are no recent UI updates.

Comment: The steps from the Web UI were as follows: Compute Engine => VM Instances => Connect SSH => (Here there was 5 or 6 options and one of them was ~= "copy and paste cli for gcloud")

Answer (score 1):

It turns out google simply moved the command off the list of options when viewing a list of instances. If you select an instance and it view its ssh options from there the "View Gcloud Command" is still there.